# How to optimize (= shorten) my Python code?

Tags: python, calculation

**My use-case is as follows:**

I want to make an electric bill generator with different units having different prices. In below program, if the user enters units between `1-150` then for making price value it will do multiplication with `2.50` and make a price. If the user Units are between the `151-300` then it will multiply the first `150` units with `2.50` and left units will multiply with the `3.60` means to say If user entered `155` then for first 150 `150 * 2.50` and for left units 5 it will do multiplication `5 * 3.60`. like the above I said I'm making like this four variations given Below:-

- if units lies between 1-150 then it will multiplies with the 2.50 and calculates the price.
- if units lies between 151-300 then it will multiplies first 150 units with the price 2.50 and left units below the 300 will multiply with the 3.60 and calculates the price.
- if units lies between 301-450 then it will multiplies first 150 units with the price 2.50 and other 150 units will multiplies with the 3.60 and left units are multiplies with the 4.75 and calculates the price.
- if units lies between 451-600 then it will multiplies first 150 units with the price 2.50 and other 150 units will multiplies with the 3.60 and other 150 units are multiplies with the 4.75 and left units are multiplies with the 5 and calculates the price.
- if units lies above 600 then it will multiplies first 150 units with the price 2.50 and other 150 units will multiplies with the 3.60 and other 150 units are multiplies with the 4.75 and next 150 units are multiplies with the 5 and left units are multiplies with the 6 and calculates the price.

**Here is my code which is seek to optimize, i.e. shorten:**

```
units = int(input("Enter the units"))
if(1<=units and 150>=units):
    firstSum = units * 2.50
    print("First sum:-", firstSum)
if(151<=units and 300>=units):
    firstSum = 150 * 2.50
    subUnits =  units - 150
    secondSum = firstSum + (subUnits * 3.60)
    print(secondSum)
if(301<=units and 450>=units):
    firstSum = 150 * 2.50
    subUnits1 = units - 150
    firstSum += 150 * 3.60
    subUnits = subUnits1 - 150
    secondSum = firstSum + subUnits * 4.75
    print(secondSum)
if(451<=units and 600>= units):
    firstSum = 150 * 2.50
    subUnits1 = units - 150
    firstSum += 150 * 3.60
    subUnits1 -= 150
    firstSum += subUnits1 * 4.75
    subUnits = subUnits1 - 150 
    secondSum = firstSum + subUnits * 5
    print(secondSum)
if(601<=units):
    firstSum = 150 * 2.50
    subUnits1 = units - 150
    firstSum += 150 * 3.60
    subUnits1 -= 150
    firstSum += subUnits1 * 4.75
    subUnits2 = subUnits1 - 150 
    firstSum += 150 * 5
    subUnits = subUnits2 - 150
    secondSum = firstSum + subUnits * 6
    print(secondSum)
```

Can any one help me to make my program in short way.

Thank you for your precious time

Comment: Your code doesn't correspond to your description. Why do you add `subUnits1*4.75` to your `firstSum` ? Shouldn't it be `firstSum += 150*4.75`? (and so on for `subUnits1*5`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, I don't think your code is doing the right thing for the two last cases. It looks like a wrong copy/paste of the previous cases ;)

I think that for the two last cases you should have :

```
if(451<=units and 600>= units):
    firstSum = 150 * 2.50
    subUnits1 = units - 150
    firstSum += 150 * 3.60
    subUnits1 -= 150
    firstSum += 150 * 4.75
    subUnits = subUnits1 - 150 
    secondSum = firstSum + subUnits * 5
    print(secondSum)
if(601<=units):
    firstSum = 150 * 2.50
    subUnits1 = units - 150
    firstSum += 150 * 3.60
    subUnits1 -= 150
    firstSum += 150 * 4.75
    subUnits2 = subUnits1 - 150 
    firstSum += 150 * 5
    subUnits = subUnits2 - 150
    secondSum = firstSum + subUnits * 6
    print(secondSum)
```

To answer your question, if I understood well, you can do something like :

```
units = int(input("Enter the units : "))
factor_list = [2.5, 3.6, 4.75, 5]
last_factor = 6
upper_bound = 600
step = 150
SUM = 0


if (units > upper_bound):
    SUM += (units-upper_bound)*last_factor
    units = upper_bound

nb150 = units/step

for i in range(0,int(nb150)):
    SUM += step*factor_list[i]

if(int(nb150) < len(factor_list)):
    SUM += (units-int(nb150)*step)*factor_list[int(nb150)]

print(SUM)
```

This solution simply avoid the multiple `if` statements by computing the euclidean division of `units`. That way you can easily change the coefficients or add others without needing to write other cases.

The first `if` statement takes care of all the units that are greater than the upper bound. It basically multiplies all the units above 600 with 6 and remove them from the units to be handled.

By the line `nb150 = units/step` and taking the integer part, I obtain the number of groups of 150 units. Then I can multiply them by their corresponding coefficient in the `for` loop.

Finally, if the number of units is lower than 600 but not a multiple of 150, the code needs to take care of the rest. So it removes the groups of 150 : `(units-int(nb150)*step)`, then multiplies the rest with the corresponding factor `factor_list[int(nb150)]`.

If you need further explanation, feel free to ask !

Comment: Nice answer @CsuGouv ! Can you motivate how you got to your solution?

Comment: @CsuGouv can you please tell me how you think this logic please

Answer (score 2):

Talking about optimization, there's quite less you can do in order to optimize the code...

You can definitely optimize it by using **if-elif-else** conditional statements instead of using just **if** :

```
if(1<=units and 150>=units):
    ...

elif(151<=units and 300>=units):
    ...

:
:

else:
    ...
```

When you are doing so, you are making sure that the condition checking doesn't happen after the right condition is reached. Thereby, reducing the number of comparisons done and optimizing the program.

Answer (score 1):

Special reason why you need it shortened? Anyway you might start by refactoring repeating code blocks into methods. For example

```
firstSum = 150 * 2.50
subUnits1 = units - 150
firstSum += 150 * 3.60
subUnits = subUnits1 - 150
```

Happens three times.

Also is there a special reasons for all the if statements instead of elif? Not that it would make the code shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding your values to variables again and again in newlines rather than binding them up in a single line. Your shorted code can be as:

```
units = int(input("Enter the units: "))
if 1<=units and 150>=units:
    print("First sum:-", units * 2.50)
elif 300>=units:
    print((150 * 2.50) + ((units - 150) * 3.60))
elif 450>=units:
    print(((150 * 2.50)+150 * 3.60) + ((units - 300) * 4.75))
elif 600>= units:
    print((((150 * 2.50) + 150 * 3.60) + (units - 300) * 4.75) + ((units - 300) - 150 ) * 5)
else:
    print(((((150 * 2.50) +150 * 3.60)+(units - 300) * 4.75)+150 * 5) + (((units - 300) - 150) - 150) * 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the unreadability here is your one-liner:

```
print(units * 2.5 + max(0, units - 150) * 1.1 + max(0, units - 300) * 1.15 + max(0, units - 450) * 0.25 + max(0, units - 600))
```

Also your example code is buggy on line 23 (`firstSum += subUnits1 * 4.75`), it should multiply with another 150 there.

Answer (score 1):

Given your code (regardless your description); you can shorten your code by doing the math, e.g.:

```
def bill_generator(units):
  firstSum = min(units, 150) * 2.5
  if units <= 300:
      secondSum = firstSum + units * 3.60 - 540.0
  elif units <= 450:
      firstSum += 540
      secondSum = firstSum + units * 4.75 - 1425.0
  elif units <= 600:
      firstSum = 540 + units * 4.75 - 1425.0
      secondSum = firstSum + units * 5.0 - 2250.0
  else:
      firstSum = 150.0 * 11.1 + units * 4.75 - 1425.0
      secondSum = firstSum + units * 6.0 - 3600.0

  print("FirstSum:-{}".format(firstSum))
  if units > 150:
    print(secondSum)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  inp_units = int(input("Enter the units: "))
  while inp_units < 1:
    print("invalid input, units must be greater than zero")
    inp_units = int(input("Enter the units"))
```

Tested the border cases:

```
def bill_generator(units):
  firstSum = min(units, 150) * 2.5
  if units <= 300:
      secondSum = firstSum + units * 3.60 - 540.0
  elif units <= 450:
      firstSum += 540.0
      secondSum = firstSum + units * 4.75 - 1425.0
  elif units <= 600:
    firstSum += 540.0 + units * 4.75 - 1425.0
    secondSum = firstSum + units * 5.0 - 2250.0
  else:
      firstSum = 1665.0 + units * 4.75 - 1425.0
      secondSum = firstSum + units * 6.0 - 3600.0

  print("FirstSum:-{}".format(firstSum))
  if units > 150:
    print(secondSum)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  for ii in [1, 150, 151, 300, 301, 450, 451, 600, 601, 1200]:
    print('Testing for unit input "{}"'.format(ii))
    bill_generator(ii)

    '''
    Testing for unit input "1"
    FirstSum:-2.5
    Testing for unit input "150"
    FirstSum:-375.0
    Testing for unit input "151"
    FirstSum:-375.0
    378.6
    Testing for unit input "300"
    FirstSum:-375.0
    915.0
    Testing for unit input "301"
    FirstSum:-915.0
    919.75
    Testing for unit input "450"
    FirstSum:-915.0
    1627.5
    Testing for unit input "451"
    FirstSum:-1632.25
    1637.25
    Testing for unit input "600"
    FirstSum:-2340.0
    3090.0
    Testing for unit input "601"
    FirstSum:-3094.75
    3100.75
    Testing for unit input "1200"
    FirstSum:-5940.0
    9540.0
    '''
```